# What are the channels for microservices to interact with each other, beyond HTTP?

Tags: architecture, protocols, microservices

I wonder if there's a better approach to build microservices-oriented system where each pair of services interact using something more appropriate than HTTP. Is there other durable options, and what may be the best one of them, for a pair of services that

- may exist on different virtual or physical machines, but mostly co-exist within one,
- require simple stream input and give stream output,
- thus, "pipeable", and
- likely written in different languages (say, Node, Clojure, Python, ...)?

Comment: All you mentioned can be found in HTTP! why do you seek another channels?

Comment: @MortezaAdi mostly from the notion that HTTP is overloaded with excessive, unnecessary metadata (headers).

Comment: None of the headers are mandatory :) http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616